# progressive web app (react app) with facebook login

Tags: reactjs, facebook-login, progressive-web-apps

i have created a react app with pwa and i integrate facebook login to manage user.

i found the problem on my android device (android ).

in the standalone app, when i click login with facebook, the app open the new embed window to sign-in with facebook account, after sign-in success, i got back to my website but still in the embed window.

i need to close this window, and re-direct to my pwa app instead.

is there any solution to fix this problem?

Comment: did you ever solve this ? I believe I'm having the same exact issue as you. I posted the question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122645/

Comment: @jasan your problem maybe different with mine. for my case, the old chrome works fine, but after update new chrome from google play. this problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely go for the cross-platform technology. ionic framework is a great way to start hybrid app development.  Cordova provides a large number of plugins, working across platforms and has many active repos in gitHub. And since it only requires you to have knowledge of basically three web technologies.(html,css,angularjs). and is the best framework for developing SPA.
SO start of with IONIC FRAMEWORK.

Comment: thanks @Rohan for your response, but why not pwa?