# Error logging into facebook using firebase javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

i have the next code:

```
let vm = this;
         console.log("LOGIN FACEBOOK WEB");
         const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
         firebase
            .auth()
            .signInWithPopup(provider)
            .then(function(result) {
                console.log(result);

            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log(error);
            });
```

But I receive the following error in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of undefined
```

I already have the project set up in facebook developers and in firebase authentication
The url I am working on is local:
http://localhost:8081/entrar/

Curiously when you start enable toggle device toolbar if you perform the redirect action to the login page.
But then the other error comes up:

```
code: "auth / canceled-popup-request"
message: "This operation has been canceled due to another conflicting popup 
being opened."
```

What could be my mistake?

Comment: What environment are you running this in?

Comment: I am working locally

Answer (score 0):

> Authenticate with Firebase using the Google provider object. You can prompt your users to sign in with their Google Accounts either by opening a pop-up window or by redirecting to the sign-in page. The redirect method is preferred on mobile devices.

original answer: [Progressive Web App (PWA) in standalone mode OAuth error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122645/progressive-web-app-pwa-in-standalone-mode-oauth-error)